# Laravel seeder is skipping records sporadically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a one to one relationship setup on two models (contacts and users). After realizing some contacts did not have a user associated with them, I'm trying to write a seeder that will catch all these cases and create the user model and associate it with the contact. However, this script only catches about half of the contacts each time. Running it repeatedly will eventually get the job done, but I would like to know what is causing this.

Models:

```php
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryUserModel;
class User extends SentryUserModel {
    public function contact()
    {
    return $this->hasOne('Contact');
    }
}
```

```php
class Contact extends AppModel {
    protected $table = 'contacts';
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

This is the seeder being run:

```php
public function run()
{
    $contacts = Contact::all();


    foreach($contacts as $contact)
    {
        $user = $contact->user;

        if(!$user))
        {
            //Logic for creating and associating new user with contact
            //This is only being hit for about half of the contacts without a user_id in the db.
            Log::info('Found a contact without a user.');
        }
    }
}
```

We would expect this seeder to catch all contacts without users and then perform the create user logic, but instead it catches about half the contacts without users and correctly creates and associates the new user. Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure how much we can help with what you've provided. How are the Users and Contacts being created in the first place? Why doesn't a Contact have a User? What does your database data look like where you're seeing no User contact, but the code isn't catching it?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check this out. Contacts and Users were originally not associated at all. This is what caused some older contacts to not be related to a user. We we're hoping this code would catch all contacts that had a null value in the the contacts.user_id column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `doesntHave()` method.
Take a look on  [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

```
public function run()
{
    $total_contacts = Contact::count();
    $total_contacts_with_user = Contact::has('user')->count();
    $total_contacts_without_user = Contact::doesntHave('user')->count();

    Log::info('Total contacts: ' . $total_contacts);
    Log::info('Total contacts with user: ' . $total_contacts_with_user);
    Log::info('Total contacts without user: ' . $total_contacts_without_user);

    Log::info('Check if this is true: ' . $total_contacts_with_user . ' + ' . $total_contacts_without_user . ' = ' . $total_contacts);
}
```

if all ok, and there are all the contacts that you expect, get the contacts without user in this way:

```
$contacts_without_user = Contact::doesntHave('user')->get();
```

and perform your creating and associating new user with contact logic

Comment: Thank you for providing a possible alternative. We simply ran the original code multiple times to catch all contacts, but we are concerned there is something wrong with the original code. We perform checks like this all over the product and if there is an issue with the seeder then it might be an indicator for problems on a larger scale. Does anything jump out at you in the original code?